kernel Version not Upgraded to Newer 24.04.1 LTS
Im using kernel version Ubuntu 22.10,Plenty of issues i faced this version no major updates found that version, So o decided to upgrade new kernel version 24.04 LTS , It showing the upgrade available but click it will be upgrade , it tell Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore., Can anyone help to resolve this issue.

We no longer answer questions about Ubuntu 22.10, and the upgrade window to 23.04 closed eight months ago. One simple and fast solution is to back up your data, clean-install Ubuntu 24.04, and mark your calendar to avoid this happening again.

Have you tried running 'sudo do-release-upgrade' as the output suggest ?

Please fresh install Ubuntu 24.04. 22.10 has reached end of support more than a year ago. While it is still possible to upgrade, that can cause a lot of issues.
